# Resetting entry_id count

Tags: ee2

Is there a way to reset the entry_id count for newly created entries?

I'm importing entries with Datagrab and need them to have entry_id's starting from 1. There are no other entries in the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have MySQL access, you can run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE exp_channel_titles AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

You can also run this command from the CP using the Database Query Form under

> Tools > Data > SQL Manager > Database Query Form

Comment: What would be the ramification of doing this with a site with existing entries?